# [fastreport]sum of fields in groupheader on fastreport

Tags: fastreport

I want to do the following action in fastreport
totext(round(Sum ({CCCTSPRD.SUMMATH}, {CCCTSPRD.TEACHER_NAME})/Sum ({CCCTSPRD.SUMMATH}, {CCCTSPRD.CLASS_NAME}),2)*100,0)+"%"
more specifically, I have a SUMMATH field which I sum according to the group, I want to extract the participation rate of group 2 from group 1 in group 2, I have tried js, processing, but I have not succeeded in anything, does anyone have a solution?